# How to supplement this regex to avoid all text between/inside specific tags (<figure>, <img>, ...)

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote regex to catch specific links in the text

`/(?<!<a href=")\b(?:(?:(?<proto>https?|ftp):)?\/\/)?(?:(?<user_pass>[\w._~%!$&'()*+,;:=-]+)@)?(?<host>(?:(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(?:xn--)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+(?<tld>[a-z]{2,63}))(?::(?<port>\d{1,5}))?(?<path>(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?)(?<query>\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(?<fragment>\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?\b(?!<\/a\>)/g`
https://regex101.com/r/ntyx3K/1

the problem is that I'm clinging values from the tags <figure>, <img>, <picture>, <trix-attachment>
[regex issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQYD.png)

so how can i update this regex to avoid values in `<figure>, <img>, <picture>, <trix-attachment>`
in the text like this https://regex101.com/r/9tMKYI/1 ?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. You'd be better off using the DOM

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: Use DOM parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @evolutionbox said, do not use regex. Try this instead:

```js
let html = 'text to catch, <figure>stuff that should not exist</figure>, <img src="stuff also not to catch">adsfsadsaf jashdfg'
let listtoavoid = ['figure', 'img']




let elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.style.display = 'none'
elem.id = 'parser'
document.body.appendChild(elem)
elem.innerHTML = html
listtoavoid.map((a, e) => {

  Array.from(elem.getElementsByTagName(a)).forEach(f => {
    f.outerHTML = `<${a}></${a}>`
  })
})
let result = elem.innerHTML
elem.innerHTML = ''
document.body.removeChild(elem)
console.log(result)
//expected output: text to catch, <figure></figure>, <img>adsfsadsaf jashdfg
```

```html
<p>other stuff in the html should not be affected unless there is a div with id='parser'</p>
```

This example makes use of DOM parsing, the act of editing HTML text by selecting and subjectively parsing certain elements. This is the simpest way of parsing HTML, which programs like regEX cannot handle gracefully.

To use my example,  simply put the string you want to parse and set it as the html variable on line 1, and then add the tags you want to avoid in the listtoavoid array on line 2, not including the <></>.

To put it as a function,

```
function parse(texttoparse, listtoavoid){
let html = texttoparse




let elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.style.display = 'none'
elem.id = 'parser'
document.body.appendChild(elem)
elem.innerHTML = html
listtoavoid.forEach((a, e) => {

  Array.from(elem.getElementsByTagName(a)).map(f => {
    f.outerHTML = `<${a}></${a}>`
  })
})
let result = elem.innerHTML
elem.innerHTML = ''
document.body.removeChild(elem)
return result
}
```

EDIT:
@Raphael Schweikert mentioned that instead of manipulation the body with a div, this could also be accomplished using the DOMparser global built into the browser:

```js
function parse(text, avoid){
  let parser = new DOMParser()
  let elem= parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html')
  avoid.forEach((a, e) => {
  
    Array.from(elem.getElementsByTagName(a)).map(f => {
      f.replaceWith(elem.createElement(a))
    })
  })
  let result = elem.body.innerHTML
  return result
}


let html = 'text to catch, <figure>stuff that should not exist</figure>, <img src="stuff also not to catch">adsfsadsaf jashdfg'
let listtoavoid = ['figure', 'img']
console.log(parse(html, listtoavoid))
```

```html
<p>HTML will not be affected at all in this example</p>
```

This uses much of the same code, although uses the DOMParser in js to globally parse the text without interference to the HTML.

Comment: Although my answer does not completely answer the question, which asked for a regex to parse text, I believe that my example, which uses DOM parsing, does the job better than any regex that did not have a considerable amount of time put into it.

Comment: Browsers have a `DOMParser` global, no need to (ab)use the `innerHTML` property for this.

Comment: It’s me again with a few minor nitpicks. 1: Mutating inside a `map` callback is discouraged, use `forEach` or a `for … of` loop. 2: Inside your `parse` function, you’re using the outer variable `listtoavoid` instead of the parameter `avoid`. 3: Setting `outerHTML` also involves parsing HTML, which is overkill, `f.replaceWith(elem.createElement(a))` would suffice.